# Trying to decipher a Kanji on a bad image source

Tags: kanji, readings, dialects

I am trying to read this unidentified Kanji

[image: unidentified Kanji]

It is some kind of house part, found on this map, as marked:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YlHL.png

It's from an older book from Nagano-ken, so it is possibly an older / now unused Kanji.

Please, if anyone can help me identify it, it is the last piece of the puzzle I am missing. Maybe it's a very simple Kanji, I don't know, right now I am at my wit's end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like 「[竈]{かまど}」 to me.  It means a "cooking stove" -- the kind where you burn wood.

Another reading is 「へっつい」 for the same meaning, but 「かまど」 is far more common.